# Sprockets::FileNotFound in Application#angular... couldn't find file 'lodash'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular, sprockets

Can someone help me?, I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

In summary I made an application in Rails that uses AngularJS for the front-end following this [AngularJS Tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails), and it works perfectly.

Now what I wanted to do was to learn to use restangular (which needs lodash I think) to avoid [these](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#wiring-everything-up) kind of code. To manage the front-end dependencies I've using `Bower`, so I followed the standard steps...

```
bower init
bower install angular angular-ui-router bootstrap lodash restangular --save
```

Then added `//= require lodash` in application.js before `//= require restangular` and `'restangular'` to the angular module dependencies...

Now **the problem is** that when I run rails s, I see this in my browser...

[image]

And I do not understand why, it seems that `//= require lodash` fails, but I've seen other projects with exactly the same `//= require lodash`, so what I'm doing wrong?

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "flapper-news",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/*****/flapper-news",
  "authors": [
    "***** <*****@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "moduleType": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests",
    "vendor/assets/bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.16",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "AngularDevise": "angular-devise#~1.1.0",
    "lodash": "~4.0.1",
    "restangular": "~1.5.1"
  }
}
```

**application.js**

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require AngularDevise
//= require angular-ui-notification
//= require lodash
//= require restangular
//= require_tree .
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'Devise', 'restangular'])

.
.
.
```

Help me please :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue when I use bower-rails to update to 4.0.1. Can't figure out why, either.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the bower_component path on `config/application.rb` ?

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
  ...
end
```

http://joelencioni.com/blog/2014/01/03/integrating-bower-with-rails/

Answer (score 1):

You can try

`//= require lodash/dist/lodash`